# How do I click a link using ng-href when the enter key is pressed

Tags: angularjs, anchor

I have a link that uses ng-href to open a new tab (why instead of ng-click is a long story involving the chrome popup blocker). The example can be found [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/o5OAj2brEENuDy87kaq1?p=preview).

Now I would like to add the ability to click the link when the enter key is pressed so I add this...

```
link: function() {
  $(document).on("keyup", function(event) {
    if (event.which == 13) {
      $("#clicking").trigger('click');
    }
  });
}
```

Everything gets called on the JS side right but the tab never opens. Any idea how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

You can confirm by adding a vanilla onclick handler to the link itself that you *are* successfully triggering the link's click event, but not the navigation.

This is because the popup blocker you were trying to work around can't be worked around that easily; browsers differentiate between user-initiated clicks and javascript-initiated clicks for exactly that reason.  Mozilla documentation, for example:

> the bubbling of a click event does not cause an  element to initiate navigation as if a real mouse-click had been received.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click

Other browsers behave similarly.

Comment: Is there a way to see this difference in the click event handler? For example if this is a non-click event use $window.open

Comment: `$window.open` would be popup-blocked as well.   Really the only way to reliably open a new window is to use a plain old link with a target.  You can set its `href` programmatically, but the click itself has to come from the user.

Comment: I ended up using ng-href for the one the selenium test runs (I need to avoid popup block) then used $window.open for the enter key (no selenium test). It would still be nice to find a way to allow the browser to click the link if enter is pressed.